# Can't save Network Connection edits

Tags: networking, 16.04, kubuntu

Kubuntu 16.04.  Right-click Networks icon in system tray, select Configure Network Connections to bring up the Connection editor.

When I try to Edit a specific connection, the "OK" button is greyed out and I can't make any changes to it.  An error popup appears that says

> Failed to get secrets for OfficeWireless.  No agents were available for this request

It only happens for the OfficeWireless connection.  I haven't been able to find any useful information for the error.  How do I edit this connection?

Comment: `nmcli co edit id <NAME>` where `<NAME>` is found in `nmcli co`

Comment: @VBF Thanks for telling me about this tool!  It helped, after I learned how to use it.  If people are still reading this question, though, I'm still interested in fixing the desktop interface.